# OpenVPN continuously restarting. Is this normal?

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, openvpn

I'm new to OpenVPN and have just set-up it up using Streisand (https://github.com/StreisandEffect) and I'm having trouble connecting to the new server. I keep getting connect refused messages even though as far as I can see, ports and firewall rules are correct.

I have noticed though that the OpenVPN service seems to be restart every 6 to 7 seconds. So that I can eliminate this or not as the potential issue, my question is, is this normal?

May 27 09:43:01 my-server-name systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN service for server.

May 27 09:43:01 my-server-name systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service for server...

May 27 09:43:01 my-server-name systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN service for server.

The above then repeats every 6 or 7 seconds.

thanks in advance
Chris.

Comment: Do you have any messages from OpenVPN itself?

Comment: hi, thanks, the message were from syslog. Where would I find the OpenVPN messages? I can't see anything in that might them in /var/log.

Comment: No, this is is not normal.